# DEPRECATION WARNING: ...Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Based on other posts and a Goog search, I have tried several variations to get rid of the deprecation warning but wind up with syntax errors in every case.

```
<%= form_for :user, @user, :url => update_reviewer_email_userhome_path do |f| %>
```

warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using form_for(:name, @resource) is deprecated. Please use form_for(@resource, :as => :name) instead.
```

I'm not sure, but I'm wondering if the fact that the model is user but the view and the update action are generated by the userhome controller.

UPDATE:

When i change to the following...

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => update_reviewer_email_userhome_path do |f| %>
```

I got this error...

```
No route matches "/userhome/19/update_reviewer_email"
```

until i changed the route from post to put:

```
  resources :userhome, :except => [:show, :new, :edit, :update, :destroy]  do
    member do
      put :update_reviewer_email
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of the `:user` part:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => update_reviewer_email_userhome_path do |f| %>
```